# Exclude certain table data for all non public schemas (tenants)

Tags: postgresql

I have tried running the pg_dump command with the following flag:

```
--exclude-table-data foo_bar
```

However it seems this flag is ignored completely if the public schema does not contain a foo_bar table. In my case foo_bar only exists for tenant schemas. Is there an undocumented function to achieve this?

Comment: A shot in the dark. Did you try: `%.foobar`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, doesn't affect the result unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name's comment I figured out the correct wildcard syntax

```
--exclude-table-data='*.foo_bar'
```